# Problema para habilitar boton

Tags: javascript, botón, elementor

estoy intentando bloquear un boton cuando escriban un codigo postal que  no concuerde con alguno del array zipCodes, el problema es que si se desactiva cuando colocas uno mal pero no se activar el boton cuando escribes codigo correcto, he probado js vanilla y jquery y con ninguno logre nada, por favor alguna solucion (en js vanilla preferiblemente)

```
<script>
let zipInput = document.querySelector('[name="form_fields[zipcode]"');

let btn = document.querySelector('.elementor-button');
  
const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710"];

  zipInput.oninput = function() {
    
    if(zipInput.value.length == 5){
        for(let i=0; i <= zipCodes.length; i++){
            
            if(zipInput.value == zipCodes[i]){
                btn.disabled = false;
            }else{
                btn.disabled = true;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
  }

</script>
```

Comment: primero puedes poner un ejemplo minimo verificable, por lo que con 5 elementos en tu arreglo bastaria, que deseas hacer y cual es el resultado esperado!

Comment: El objetivo es que un formulario al escribir un codigo postal, se desactive o active un boton del formulario dependiendo si el codigo postal esta dentro del array zipCodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas:

- El evento `oninput`
- Y la funcion [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) que evaluará si existe algún elemento que cumple la condición

Un ejemplo

```js
const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710"];
var inputzip=document.getElementById("inputzip");
var boton=document.getElementById("boton");
inputzip.oninput = x => boton.disabled=!zipCodes.some(a=>a===inputzip.value)
```

```html
<input id="inputzip"  >
<button id="boton" disabled>algo</button>
```

---

Por otro lado, el problema de tu código es que el for no se detiene cuando encuentra un elemento. Es decir puede hacer `btn.disabled = false;`, pero luego sigue recorriendo y lo vuelve a poner en  `btn.disabled = true;`. Tu código debería ser:

```js
let zipInput = document.getElementById('inputzip');

let btn = document.querySelector('.elementor-button');
  
const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710"];

zipInput.oninput = function() {
 btn.disabled = true;
  if(zipInput.value.length == 5){
      for(let i=0; i <= zipCodes.length; i++){
          if(zipInput.value == zipCodes[i]){
              btn.disabled = false;
              break;
          }

      }
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="inputzip">
<button class="elementor-button" disabled>boton</button>
```

Fíjate como hacemos `btn.disabled = true;` al inicio, para establecer que es el valor default y cuando encontramos un elemento que cumple la condición hacemos un `break` para terminar la iteración

Comment: No puedo colocar esa funcion en el input porque estoy haciendo esto en elementor, alguna forma de hacer lo mismo en un script de js?

Comment: AH claro me falta agregar el break, voy a probar eso

Comment: Creo que tienes un error en la línea de `inputzip.oninput`.

Comment: Nada. Está todo junto y pensé que `=!` estaba mal.

Answer (score 0):

Algo mucho más sencillo sería verificar que el valor del `input` se encuentra en el array con la función [**`includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), si se encuentra, quitamos el `disabled` del botón, de lo contrario, el botón se mantendrá con el `disabled`.

Recuerda que esto se ejecutará mientras se escuche el `listener` del `keyup` (o sea, mientras escribamos en el input, se escucha el `listener` y se ejecuta todo lo de adentro). Ejemplo (explicación en comentarios):

```js
let zipInput = document.querySelector('.zipInput'); // capturo el input.
let btn = document.querySelector('.elementor-button'); // capturo el botón.

const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710"]; // defino el array que buscaré.

// Este listener se ejecutará si ocurre el evento "keyup" en el input, es decir,
// cada vez que escribamos en el input, el listener ejecutará toda la función de adentro.
zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  let value = zipInput.value; // entonces, cada vez que se ingrese al listener, capturamos al valor del input...
  if (zipCodes.includes(value)) { // y verificamos que si ese valor se encuentra en el array...
    btn.disabled = false; // si encuentra, el botón se habilitará...
  } else {
    btn.disabled = true; // de lo contrario, permanecerá deshabilitado.
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="zipInput">
<button class="elementor-button" disabled>Buscar</button>
```

```js
let zipInput = document.querySelector('.zipInput');
let btn = document.querySelector('.elementor-button');

const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710"];

zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  let value = zipInput.value;
  if (zipCodes.includes(value)) {
    btn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="zipInput">
<button class="elementor-button" disabled>Buscar</button>
```

Comment: Esta interesante esta forma pero yo no quiero usar keyup

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso no es lo mismo que oninput?

Comment: Claro, es lo mismo, pero quise darte otra alternativa diferente a la que te dieron...

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy a probar esta opcion porque quizas vaya mas rapido que usando for ya que es menos codigo